# How to compute the homomorphism module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I want to compute the homomorphism module $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z} /{p^{n}}, \mathbb{Z} /{p^{m}})$ for $m\leq n$.

Can someone please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a $\mathbf{Z}$-module is equivalent to an abelian group. Similarly, a $\mathbf{Z}$-module homomorphism is equivalent to an abelian group homomorphism. Thus, we can consider this as a purely group theory question.

A homomorphism between cyclic groups is completely determined by where it sends a generator. Take a generator for $\mathbf{Z} / p^n$. Then it has order $p^n$ so its image must have order a factor of $p^n$. However, in the group $\mathbf{Z} / p^m$, all elements have order dividing $p^m$. Since $m \le n$, then $p^m \mid p^n$. Thus, there are no restrictions for the map and so we conclude that it is equal to $\mathbf{Z} / p^m$.

Since you tagged this as homological algebra, I am guessing this arose in calculating $\textrm{Ext}$. By applying the same reasoning, you can easily deduce the following:

> $$\textrm{Ext}_\mathbf{Z}^0 (\mathbf{Z} / n , D) = \textrm{Hom} (\mathbf{Z} / n, D) = \{d \in D \mid nd = 0\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! But there are two points i do not understand.  1. " Thus, there are no restrictions for the map and so we conclude that it is equal to $\mathbf{Z}/ p^{m}$ ". 2."$Hom(\mathbf{Z}/n, D)=\{ d \in D | nd= 0 \}$".

Comment: I know  $Hom_{\mathbf{Z}}(Z/n,D)=\{ d∈D \  | \ nd=0 \}$.

Comment: The only restriction was that the order be a factor of $p^n$, which is satisfied by all elements of the group.